# Hide Button That Have “blablalba” Text - java swing?

Tags: java

It Is Possible to hide button depend on what it has text ? Like :-

```
b2.setVisible(false);
```

Instead of using a name, we use the text it contains, for example

```
"text on button".setVisible(false);
```

If Not Can You Give Me Any Way To Call Button That Have Same Name ? Or How Can I Get The Virable Name For Buttons That It Is New And I Add It to 'jpanal'; ?

My Code Is That I Have Loop To Add 10 Button That Have Name (b2) With `ActionListener` ; What I Need To Do Is If I Need To Call A 1 button From Another Class , How i will call it ?!

```
    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

        for(int i = 0 ; i <=10 ; i ++){


            JButton b2= new JButton();

              b2.addActionListener(new Action() {
        @Override
        public Object getValue(String key) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void putValue(String key, Object value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b2.getText());

        }

 });

 b2.setText("My Name" + i);

b2.setBackground(Color.white);

b2.setFont(font);

  this.jPanel1.add(b2);

         this.jPanel1.validate();

       SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);

 }

    }
```

So let's say I want to hide my button with the name "My Name 5" But i need to call it from another class how can i do this ?

[image For Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHIvR.jpg)

Comment: *"Or How Can I Get The Virable Name For Buttons"* You can't, not in Java.  The solution you are looking for is either an `array` or `List` or `Map`, depending your needs.  Other considerations are; You could use [`get/putClientProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) to associate data with the component

Comment: Can you Edit My Code To Be Work With Map ? Or Array ? and how i will set the Virable Name For Buttons Using Array ?